Optimal choice of tires in race
Formula 1 started this weekend. And I have been trying to figure out how they calculate the optimum choice of tires to finish the race fastest.
While in the real F1 race there are many factors including track position and weather to be considered, I would like to understand the math of this problem with the following model:
You are given a set of tires where tires$[i] = [f_i, r_i]$ indicates that the $i$-th tire can finish its $x$-th successive lap in $f_i r_i^{x-1}$ seconds.
For example, if $f_i = 3$ and $r_i = 2$, then the tire would finish its 1st lap in $3$ seconds, its 2nd lap in $3 \times 2 = 6$ seconds, its 3rd lap in $3 \times 2^2 = 12$ seconds, etc. You are also given an integer changeTime and an integer numLaps.
The race consists of numLaps laps and you may start the race with any tire. You have an unlimited supply of each tire and after every lap, you may change to any given tire (including the current tire type) if you wait changeTime seconds.
How to calculate the minimum time to finish the race?
I found this question on leetcode, where people use dynamic programming to solve it. I have been seeking the non-discrete approach for this problem. How would you do it in math?
This question is relevant to me as a software engineer that comes from a physics background. I would like to understand more why the two fields don't seem to blend.

I made some guesses as to what you meant by “ri(x-1)” based on your later example. If this is not what you intended, feel free to edit it further to clarify the problem.
